# In TexShop on Mac OS, I want to change the Switch <-> Preview Command from CMD+1

Tags: mac, texshop, macos

I am using MacOS system preferences to change the default commands in TeXShop. It's necessary to type in the exact name of the menu command in order to change it.

I want to change the Switch <-> Preview Command from CMD+1, however, I don't know what the name of this command is exactly. I've tried "Source Preview", "Source $\Leftrightarrow$ Preview".

The instructions for changing default keybindings as I understand them are linked here: 
https://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2008-March/034602.html

Does anyone know the exact name of the menu item that I need to use?
If not, is anyone familiar with a workaround for this particular problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact menu title is "Source ⇔ Preview" (⇔ is the Unicode character U+21D4).

Here is a screenshot of the French TexShop (Preview is translated as "Aperçu"), as an example I have changed the shortcut from `cmd+1` to `ctrl+alt+shift+cmd+&`.

[image]

Comment: Mine came up as u+21D4... but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @fantasticasm89 You're right, I misread 4 as A (I must clean my glass).